# Multidimensional Array with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am trying to export a multidimensional array as excell file using phpexcel librery. Somehow i cant get beyond exporting a file with the groupname in columne's.

My code:

```
    $arr = array(
             "group1"=>array(
                    1001 => array(
                            "name"=>"Product 1",
                            "desc"=>"lorem ipsum",
                            "star"=>"3",
                            "price"=>"15"
                            ),
                    1002 => array(
                            "name"=>"Pedruzka",
                            "desc"=>"Speck, Zwiebeln",
                            "star"=>"2",
                            "price"=>"17"
                            )
        ),
            "group2"=>array(
                    1001 => array(
                            "name"=>"Margherita",
                            "desc"=>"Tomaten, Mozzarella, Oregano",
                            "star"=>"3",
                            "price"=>"15"
                            ),
                    1002 => array(
                            "name"=>"Pedruzka",
                            "desc"=>"Speck, Zwiebeln",
                            "star"=>"2",
                            "price"=>"17"
                            )
)
    )
```

Code for export:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();  

 ......

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i).'1', $key);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue(PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($i+1).'2', $value);
        $i++;
    }

   .....
```

Comment: Well you are only using 1 loop when you actually need 3...

Comment: can you please help by giving some code examples? i tried to accomplish this but run into more issues?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way to explain the situation, is to just explain you how loops works. A `foreach` loop will give you the `key` and the `value`.

So based on your first loop you use:

the (first) key will be: `group1`,

the value for this key contains:

```
array("name"=>"Product 1",
      "desc"=>"lorem ipsum",
      "star"=>"3",
      "price"=>"15"
     )
```

So basically what you need to do is use an extra loop.
If you want to understand better you can find the [full example](https://3v4l.org/qXVIK) here.

Basically what you are going to do is:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2){
        //do stuff with PHPExcel
        //call items in array by key
        $name = $value2["name"];  
        $price = $value2["price"];  
    }
}
```